# TinyMCE - Pass value from Popup

Tags: tinymce, django-tinymce

I am using TinyMCE  . On a Click I am opening an inline popup successfully.But I have no idea how I can pass a value from popup to tinyMCE.Any help highly appreciated.

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.open({
    file : "options.jsp",
    title : 'Image Manager',
    width : 800, 
    height : 600,
    resizable : "yes",
    inline : "yes", 
    close_previous : "no",
    win : window
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took me some time to find it out myself. It is not that difficult. To insert HTML to your editor from the popup you may use something like

```
var my_html_code = 'New phrase!';
tinyMCEPopup.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, my_html_code);
```

Using `tinyMCEPopup.editor` you may address the editor from where you opened the popup.
You could for example set a variable in the editor using

```
tinyMCEPopup.editor.new_variable = 'blah blah';
```

Comment: Sorry, but I did't understood your answer. Could you answer to the question "How to put a value from external popup to tinymce?".